# Why does git pack protocol only negotiate what commit to send during packfile negotiation?

Tags: git

From what I can gather from [git-scm docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-protocol), packfile negotiation ends when the client think the server know what commits to send, and then packfile is sent immediately. Well even if the commit is new, some of the content might already exist on the client, **why not negotiate down to what files need to be sent as well?** Is it because negotiating down to this level of detail is not worth the effort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is unchanged between the commit being sent, and one which was discovered to be common, this can be handled without further negotiation: if the client has commit X, it must also have all the blobs in the tree of commit X.

If a blob with the same hash happens to exist in a commit which was not part of the negotiation, it would be possible to negotiate not to send it. In practice, though, this would probably be rare: you'd need a file on the server and a file in the client which were identical, but which had not appeared in the history which was already shared.

More common is that the file to be sent can be described by some delta from a previous version of the file. That's handled by the [pack format](https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-format) - the server can send a delta with a base object it knows the client has.

If the server had a perfect view of the client's list of objects, it could optimise both the blobs it sent and how to deltify them, but the bandwidth to transmit that complete list would often be higher than the bandwidth saved.

Comment: Besides this, we also know that—except with a shallow clone, which is marked as such—the presence of commit X implies the presence of *all predecessor commits*. So the short version of this answer is "yes" :-) but the longer one might add "but further negotiation *might* be worthwhile in some cases" (including shallow clones).

Comment: @torek Even with a shallow clone, there'd have to be a specific set of circumstances that led to the client happening to have a blob that wasn't in any of the commits mentioned in the negotiation. Something like the same file introduced identically in two different branches, or deleted and recreated on one of them, perhaps.

Comment: Yes, though actually the one particularly common case is that, when you make a shallow clone with depth 1 and modify one file and `git push`, you wind up pushing a pack that has every file. Make your clone with depth 2 and `git push` and you push only the deltas for changed or new files. This is sort of a bug, since the sender saw the receiver had the commit. The problem here is in the enumeration, I think.